# Grunt code coverage doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, istanbul

I've the following grunt file which runs the mocha tests OK (I get results of the test after running grunt.js)Now I want to add a code and I use the https://github.com/taichi/grunt-istanbul module. but when I run the grunt.js nothing happen,any idea?

What I want is simply after that mocha test are running it will run the **code coverage with some reports**? any new code coverage will be great

**This is my project structure**

```
myApp
 -server.js
 -app.js
 -test
   -test1.spec
   -test2.spec
 -test-reports
 -grunt.js
 -utils
  -file1.js
  -file2.js
 -controller
  -file1.js
  -file2.js
```

This is the code inside the grunt for what I've tried

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var path = require('path');

    process.env.RESOURCE_PATH_PREFIX = "../";
    var d = new Date();

    var datestring = d.getDate() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getFullYear() + " " +
        d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

    var npmCommand = path.dirname(process.execPath).concat('/npm');
    var reportDir = "./test-reports/" + datestring;


    grunt.initConfig({
        jasmine_nodejs: {
            // task specific (default) options
            options: {
                specNameSuffix: ["-spec.js"], 
                helperNameSuffix: "helper.js",
                useHelpers: false,
                stopOnFailure: false,
                reporters: {
                    console: {
                        colors: true,            
                    },
                    junit: {
                        savePath: "./test-reports",
                        filePrefix: "testresult",
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                specs: [
                    "test/*",
                ]
            },
            makeReport: {
              src: './test-reports/coverage.json',//should I create this file?or its created automatically ?
               options: {
                 type: ['lcov', 'html'],
                   dir: reportDir,
                   print: 'detail'
        }
    },
    coverage: {
        APP_DIR_FOR_CODE_COVERAGE: "./utils/*.js",//HERE IS THE PATH OF THE UTILS Folder which all the js login which I want to test there
        clean: ['build'],
        instrument: {
            files: tasks,//WHAT IS TASKS????
            options: {
                lazy: true,
                basePath: 'build/instrument/'//I DONT KNOW WHAT IT IS???
            }
        },
        reloadTasks: {
            rootPath: 'build/instrument/tasks'//SHOULD I USE IT????
        },
        storeCoverage: {
            options: {
                dir: reportDir
            }
        }
    }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jasmine-nodejs');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-istanbul');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jasmine_nodejs']);
    grunt.registerTask('cover', ['instrument', 'test',
        'storeCoverage', 'makeReport']);

};
```

If there is mocha code coverage which can help it will be great either, I want that after I run the test I will able to see report with all the code coverage.

I want that the coverage will be **done for folder utils and controller** (all the files there) how should I config that?

UPDATE

This is what I use for jasmin and I think I should change to mocha

```
jasmine_nodejs: {
            // task specific (default) options
            options: {
                specNameSuffix: ["-spec.js"], // also accepts an array
                helperNameSuffix: "helper.js",
                useHelpers: false,
                stopOnFailure: false,
                reporters: {
                    console: {
                        colors: true,
                        cleanStack: 1,       // (0|false)|(1|true)|2|3
                        verbosity: 4,        // (0|false)|1|2|3|(4|true)
                        listStyle: "indent", // "flat"|"indent"
                        activity: false
                    },
                    junit: {
                        savePath: "./test-reports",
                        filePrefix: "testresult",
                        consolidate: true,
                        useDotNotation: true
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                // target specific options
                options: {
                    useHelpers: false
                },
                // spec files
                specs: [
                    "test/*",
                ]
            }
        },
```

How should I change it?
**The syntax of my test are similar(jasmine/mocha) and what I want is simply to run my test and after run the code coverage**

Comment: are you willing to use `mocha` instead of `jasmine`?

Comment: Remember that "code coverage" is just a metric that compares number of lines. https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/are-test-coverage-metrics-overrated It's easily gamed.

Comment: also remember that "testing" is just code that runs other code. It's easily gamed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll give you an indirect answer. I've gotten code coverage to work before, but with a different plugin (and with mocha). I'm not sure if you're open to swapping out `jasmine` for `mocha` but I will say that I struggled with various code coverage plugins before coming across this one. I think you'll agree the configuration is both concise and obvious.

The plugin you want is [grunt-mocha-istbanbul](https://github.com/pocesar/grunt-mocha-istanbul), and here is a sample configuration for your `Gruntfile`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    clean: ['coverage'],
    mocha_istanbul: {
      coverage: {
        src: 'test',
        options: {
          timeout: 20000,
          'report-formats': 'html',
          print: 'summary',
          check: {
            lines: 90,
            statements: 90,
            functions: 100,
            branches: 80
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-istanbul');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'mocha_istanbul']);
}
```

Comment: HI Kevin thanks,I dont care to switch this is fine as soon as it work :)  ,where should I put the path for the utils& controller folder? how I run the report

Comment: Um, like I said, there are a lot of code coverage plugins out there that are super annoying to try to configure, either because they're under-documented or because the github page doesn't provide a working example. I was just letting you know that I happen to know of a decent coverage plugin that is really easy to get working. It's next to impossible to say why your example doesn't work, unless (someone) already has a working example for that plugin.

Comment: and I've never used jasmine before, but in a quick read it appears they are extremely similar. So it might be to your benefit to just switch and fix any minor differences in your tests.

Comment: Hi Kevin I want to use the plugin you mentions but where I put the reference to the tests folder like utils and controllers ?

Comment: and since I newbe to grunt can you please provide the all code which should I use.

Comment: Also I haven't used this particular option before, but the `includes` option looks like the one (or `excludes`, if that happens to be easier), to only include specific folders in the coverage report: https://github.com/pocesar/grunt-mocha-istanbul#optionsincludes

Comment: HI Kevin 1+ ,its seems that something has start to work but I got error jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;
^

ReferenceError: jasmine is not defined , how can I change my code and remove the jasmine(inside my grunt file- since my test runs mocha)

Comment: Inside two test file (spec) I use jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000; and jasmine is not defined ?im using in the gruntfile https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node which I guess should be changed to mocha? do you know how? I update my question with the exact entry which I use

Comment: inside your `describe` function you can do `this.timeout(20000)` which should achieve the same thing (for a specific test file). The default is 2000ms if you don't specify anything. Or you can pass a parameter to mocha (via mocha_istanbul) to set the default timeout across all tests.

Comment: I updated. You just set `timeout:20000` in the options block in the `Gruntfile`